# Add "This is not an answer" as feedback option in first answers review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-answers

Right now the [first answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers) Has the options "Answer is unclear", "Answer needs supporting information" and "Custom comment"

First answers that are NAA (not an answer) are fairly common. I suggest adding the option "Answer is not an answer" with a corresponding explanation. Maybe something like:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment or another question.

I'm aware that it should be flagged, but I think an additional comment is a nice thing. It gives the poster the option to remove the answer themselves.

Comment: If something is not an answer, one should be flagging instead of posting a comment, right?

Comment: @yivi Yes, it should be flagged. But not necessarily instead of commenting.

Comment: Comments are considered noise. You can post a custom comment if you think it will help (there are also canned comments available) but a flag on its own is enough. It's highly unlikely that a person who ignored all information when posting the NAA will read your comment.

Comment: I think you should flag as NAA and choose "Other action".

Comment: @justANewbie That's what I am doing. But I would like to leave a comment too.

Comment: Can you explain why posting a comment makes it possible for the author to delete it themselves and why flagging it as NAA does not serve that purpose? Is this about the notification they get because of the comment?

Comment: @Gimby Yes, it's about the notification

Comment: But don't you also get a notification when the answer is closed due to it being flagged? Serious question, I actually don't know that for sure.

Comment: @Gimby *answers* do not get closed - questions do. The result of the flag is deletion (possibly + conversion to comment) and I'm not sure if that produces a notification. I think it doesn't.

Comment: @VLAZ Jeepers, I really had the impression that answers could also be marked as off-topic. You're right of course, I don't know where my brain is.